# How does using Executors.newCachedThreadPool() make sure there is no starving task

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Context:
I have an async API method that returns a ListenableFuture. But, clients have sync code that they are doing a `Future.get()` on this API (which is not ideal). But to mitigate the effect of starvation (task A depends on B, but B is waiting for a thread in pool to be available to start), I am thinking to use unbounded threadpool for running the async task (v/s currently it is running on a bounded threadpool). I am trying to see how much of a help it will be.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but if I understand this correctly, the [Executors.newCachedThreadPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--)  is an unbounded threadpool. But, the underlying OS threads are still [limited `numThreads`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors--). So, if I spawn `numThreads + 1` tasks and numThreads task are waiting for that 1 task to be done, but that 1 task cannot even start because it does not have a thread avaialble, how does an unbounded threadpool help in this case? (v/s compared to a bounded threadpool)

Comment: Did you ever hear of “preemptive multitasking”? Did you ever compare the number of programs running on your system (not to speak of the total number of their threads) with the number of CPU cores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of CPUs/cores does not limit the number of threads.
[Preemptive multi-tasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)), as mentioned in the comments, makes sure no thread can cause starvation in the system (compare to [cooperative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking)).
There are different implementations in the modern operating systems (and if I recall it correctly Windows was allowing to select a kernel version during the installation, with different schedulers/multi-tasking implementations).